# Is this an example of implicit verbs?

Tags: verbs

> The greater the intensity of hard work, greater is the success.
>
> The greater **is** the intensity of hard work, greater is the success.

Are these sentences grammatical?

Does the first one has verb implied in itself?

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are wrong, although more because of the second clause than the first: "More is the success" makes no sense. The first clause of the first sentence is fine, the first clause of the second sentence is not

Instead, I'd say something like the following as the most direct translation of what I think you're trying to say here.

> The greater the intensity of the work, the greater the [chance of] success.

Or, depending on context, I may vary it to one of the following

> The harder you work, the more likely you are to succeed.
>   If you work harder, you are more likely to succeed.
>   If you work harder, you will achieve more. (This sentence is slightly different, as we change the focus to what you actually achieve being more impressive/desirable, rather than the chance of achieving it)

There's no need to mention that the work is hard, because you're already talking about greater intensity.

Comment: Excluding the second clause, my question what difference it does make by placing the verb **is** in the first clause remains unanswered.